# Bayesian Prior definition

Tags: bayesian, inference, prior

The prior of an inference problem where we try to infer $x$ from observations $y$ is defined as $P(X)$. Often ([e.g.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.5141.pdf)) I see another definition where the prior is defined as $P(X|Q)$, what exactly is $Q$ in that context, are those the hyperparameters as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference#:%7E:text=Bayesian%20inference%20is%20a%20method,and%20especially%20in%20mathematical%20statistics.)?

Comment: I was going to suggest $Q$ was the background context known or assumed to be true, but your first link says: An input vector $\mathbf q \in Q^n$ has components $q_j \in Q$ for some set $Q$ and generates an unknown random vector $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$ through a componentwise input channel described by a conditional distribution $p_{X\mid Q}(x_j \mid q_j )$.  So there $Q$ contains the possible values of $q_j$